# java how to iterate through json object to get keys AND values

Tags: java, json, loops

I'M searching for a solution to a problem, that, from my understanding, should be fairly common.

I have a bunch of json objects with different keys (some represent a user, some a text by the user, some a place). Now what I need to do is, create a dataset in my key-value store db (happens to be an embedded neo4j) for every json object to come in - I need to use the java interface not the rest interface.

The problem is, I do not know the json layout (names of keys) during compile time - well of course I do know them for each object type, but I don't want to write a bunch of methods for each and every object type but rather a generic method. So I thought, well, no big deal, I just create an entry with the key being the json-key and the value being the json-value.

BUT, I can't, for the sake of whatever, find a solution to iterate over a json structure and retrieve the key-names. Every solution I found so far, expects the keynames to be known in advance to get the value.

Is there any way of doing so??? Is this such a rare situation? I would have expected this to be quite a common a task.

Can anyone help???
Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: Which of the dozens of JSON APIs are you using? Point us to its javadoc.

Comment: If you have a `JSONObject`, that for example has a method called`keys()` which gives you an Iterator:`java.util.Iterator keys() Get an enumeration of the keys of the JSONObject.` but this depends on the JSON API you are using